# Searching an employee object in an array of employee objects

Tags: java

This is my program:

```
class EmP
{
    int id;
    Emp(int id)
    {
        this.id=id;
    }
    int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    int find(Emp[] emp)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<emp.length;i++)
        { 
            if(emp[i]==emp[i])
                return i;
            else
                return -1;
        }
        System.out.println("successfull");
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Emp emp[]={new Emp(1),new Emp(2),new Emp(3)};
        find(emp[0]);
    }
}
```

This program finds if an employee object is present in array or not. I am getting an error when I compile this program. May I know what's wrong with this program?

Comment: Every compiler has a log where it says what is wrong with your code if copmilations fails

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: 1. Format your code. 2. What error do you get ?

Comment: From the code I'm seeing several errors, which are not only syntactical but also logical. Which do you want to solve?

Comment: Yes; the compiler knows exactly what's wrong, and just told you in the error message.

Comment: Presumably you cannot pass an `EmP` into a method that takes an `EmP[]`. Your logic is also rather flawed, `emp[i]` always `==emp[i]`.

Comment: The compile error is due to the invokation of your find method with the argument emp[0] which is an instance (object) of type Emp but your find method expects an array of type Emp. Next to it your find method has some logical errors, which were already mentioned above.

Answer (score 5):

You should **always** tell the error message when asking questions. Those things exist for a reason. However, I think it has to do with this:

`public class EmP {`

While everywhere else you use the classname `Emp` (notice the lowercase "p"). Case matters in Java, don't forget! There is also another syntax error:

```
find(emp[0]);
```

`find` is not a `static` method so you need to call it on an object instance. Furthermore, `emp[0]` is not a `Emp[]` so the argument type is mismatched. For example, `emp[0].find(emp)` would be syntactically correct.

Finally, your `find` method is semantically incorrect.

```
if(emp[i]==emp[i])
    return i;
else
    return -1;
```

You're just checking if the object in `emp[i]` is the same as itself. Also, in the event it wasn't, you'd give up the search immediately without checking the rest of the array. Use the `this` object instead, and only return `-1` once you've searched the entire array without finding a match.

You've got a lot to fix in there.

Answer (score 2):

This is why you look at the errors shown by your compiler. IDEs show this before you even execute the program, you just have to go over the list and fix.

1. Your class is named `EmP`, everything else is `Emp`.
2. Your `find()` method doesn't always return an `int`. If the `for` loop doesn't get executed, it won't return anything.
3. `if(emp[i]==emp[i])` doesn't make much sense.
4. Your method `find()` expects `Emp[]` but receives `Emp`.
5. You can't actually call the method `find()`, it's not known in that context.
6. You don't use the result of the method `find()`.

Answer (score 0):

There about 5-6 issues that @JeroenVannevel and @kviiri found. Don't want to write the same. According to `This program finds if an employee object is present in array or not`

I think it should be something like that:

```
public class EmP{
    int id;

    public EmP(int id){
        this.id=id;
    }

    int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    static boolean find(EmP[] emp, EmP target){
        int i;

        for(i=0;i<emp.length;i++){
            if(emp[i].getId()==target.getId())
                return true; // found
        }

        return false; // not found
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        EmP emp[]={new EmP(1),new EmP(2),new EmP(3)};

        EmP e =  new EmP(1);
        boolean status = find(emp, e);    
        System.out.println("the employee with id " + e.getId() + " found: " + status);

        e =  new EmP(7);    
        status = find(emp, e);    
        System.out.println("the employee with id " + e.getId() + " found: " + status);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
the employee with id 1 found: true
the employee with id 7 found: false
```

Comment: thanks a lot, ur program helped me!

Comment: @user3099939 generally if you feel that this answer helped you, you welcome to accept a.e. "V"